# How to compare hashed passwords stored as strings in python using bcrypt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, passwords, bcrypt

So I have a database where a bunch of hashed passwords are stored in strings. Now I am trying to then pull them down, and compare them to the plain text passwords the user enters. Here is an example:

```
import bcrypt

# at creation first:
password = u"seCr3t"
hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
print(hashed_password)

#example of it being stored in the database
hashed_password = str(hashed_password)


# first attempt:
password = u"seCrEt"
print(bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), hashed_password.encode('utf8')))
# -> False

# second attempt:
password = u"seCr3t"
print(bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), hashed_password.encode('utf8')))
# -> True


# However I get the error "Invalid Salt"
```

I don't know how to get around this error and have not been able to find much about it online. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're casting the password to string. Use decode and encode to ensure the password gets converted to string and back using the same format.

```
import bcrypt

password = u"seCr3t"
hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf8'), bcrypt.gensalt())

# convert to string with correct format
string_password = hashed_password.decode('utf8')

password = u"seCr3t"
# convert back to bytes with correct format
print(bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), string_password.encode('utf8')))
# True
```

I'm not an expert on encoding formats by any means, so this may not work in all cases. If you have a character in your bytes object that can't be represented using utf8, it could cause problems. I'd look into best practices for storing passwords. Maybe you could even use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) which allows you to store python objects directly.

Comment: That does not work you will run into this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Passwordhashtest.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), hashed_password))
  File "C:\Users\justi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bcrypt\__init__.py", line 101, in checkpw
    raise TypeError("Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking")
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking`

Comment: Working fine for me on bcrypt 3.1.4 and python 3.6.0. What version are you using? What OS?

Comment: I just installed bcrypt so I would assume the most up to date version, and I am on Windows 10 python 3.6

Comment: That backtrace you posted looks like the error is on line 14, and my example isn't that long. Did you copy and run the example exactly?

Comment: I edited my code to match yours. Let me try that exact example

Comment: It worked! I must have messed something up in translation. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem at all :)

Comment: Wait sorry I just realized this isn't solving my problem. You removed where the hash is converted into a string. This is what causes the issue. I pull the hash down from a database so it has to come in string form. This solution does not address that issue.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you use decode instead of casting to string to convert the bytes to string, it'll work. I'd look into the best way to store passwords though. I'm not sure this solution is optimal.Also, you'd have to ensure that your users can only enter utf8 compatible characters when setting their password.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried in ipython (python 3.10):

```
import bcrypt

# at creation first:
password = u"seCr3t"
hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
print(hashed_password)

#example of it being stored in the database
hashed_password = str(hashed_password)


# first attempt:
password = u"seCrEt"
print(bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), bytes(hashed_password.replace("b'", "").replace("'", ""), 'utf-8')))
# -> False

# second attempt:
password = u"seCr3t"
print(bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), bytes(hashed_password.replace("b'", "").replace("'", ""), 'utf-8')))
# -> True
```

That way it works.
The output was:

```
b'$2b$12$jYlhIXVWLMxBQDZ9QJH./e980gBUEy7PoDAMupnhcqQObVF7rQZW2'
False
True
```

[image]